# PHP variable treated as empty unless it is echoed

Tags: php

I'm defining a variable, $location, on a page called index.php and then using it when I set the header in a script called loginManager.php. If I simply use $location PHP insists that it is empty. However, if I echo the variable anywhere on the page it will recognize the contents of the variable.

Here is the relevant code:

index.php:

```
$location = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/lib/loginManager.php");
```

loginManager.php:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/?location=$location");
echo $location;//Adding this line allows PHP to read the contents of $location.
               //If this line is commented out PHP treats it as if it were empty.
```

The code running on loginManager.php is not in a function or anything that would cause scoping problems with $location. Does anyone have any idea why PHP would behave in this way?

EDIT:
I will expand on how I know PHP thinks $location is empty when I do not echo it somewhere on the page.

If I do something like:

```
If(empty($location))
    echo "location is empty";
else
    print "location is not empty";
```

PHP will print out "location is empty".

However, if I do something like this

```
echo $location;
If(empty($location))
    echo "location is empty";
else
    print "location is not empty";
```

PHP will print out "location is not empty". It does not seem to matter where I echo $location out.

EDIT #2:
@jx12345 pointed out that it's not $location specifically that needs to be echoed, just that something needs to be echoed in order for $location to be read.

Comment: what happens if you use header("Location: $_POST[caller]?location={$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");

Comment: What does a `var_dump()` say just to make sure?

Comment: var_dump($location) gives: 
string(16) "/tutoring/tutor/" 

which is exactly what $location should contain.

Comment: @Tavarius So why not try something like `$location = "http://" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) . ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: Also, $location has to be set on the other page because the whole point of it is to keep track of the page that is calling the loginManager.php script, so the other suggestions won't work.

Comment: @Tavarius Including my suggestion above?

Comment: @Fred Yep setting $location is not the problem, it's just that PHP refuses to read $location unless it is printed on the page.

Comment: @Tavarius: That makes no sense.  What do you mean by "refuses to read"?  So it works if you `echo "Location: $_POST[caller]?location=$location";`, but not if you `header("Location: $_POST[caller]?location=$location");`?

Comment: @Tavarius Hm... let me think for a bit, going to try and "OutFox the Fox", as it were ;-)

Comment: @Tavarius I'm curious. Can you give me an example of the desired output, using `http://example.com` as an example?

Comment: @OmarJackman That's what I was also thinking. I can't know for sure unless I can replicate the same conditions.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat see the update in my post

Comment: @Fred Ideally I want the header to look like this: header("Location: http://www.example.com/location"). However, when I do not echo $location it looks like this: header("Location: http://www.example.com/").

Comment: @Tavarius And could location also be a file name, or does it have to be a folder?

Comment: What happens if you echo something other than $location?

Comment: @jx12345 Nice insight - I hadn't thought of that. I don't have to echo $location specifically, I just have to echo something.

Comment: @Fred $location can be a file name. It can be any string really I just want it to show up as a $_GET variable.

Comment: @Tavarius `jx12345` has a point there, since your `?location` is `$location` right?

Comment: do you use any output buffering like ob_start

Comment: No I don't use output buffering, and I have it disabled in php.ini.

Comment: @Tavarius You just said `GET` and you're using `$_POST[caller]`? Didn't you try using `$_GET[caller]` instead? I'm starting to get confused. This one is starting to consume me LOL! hey, don't get me wrong, I'm looking to help :)

Comment: @Fred Right, I set the header with a $_POST variable and read it with a $_GET variable on another page. I don't think $_POST or $_GET have anything to do with it though.

Comment: @Tavarius Ok. So try adding something like `$caller = $_GET[caller];` (or POST), make sense in a way as to what `jx12345` mentioned.

Comment: @Fred For all intents and purposes the header is this: header("Location: http://www.example.com/?location=$location");. The problem is with $location and not anything else.

Comment: When you're loading the first page in the browser are you doing it with http://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/index.php, cos if it was the former wouldn't REQUEST_URI be empty?

Comment: @Tavarius How about this `$location2 = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); header("Location: http://www.example.com/?location=$location2");` I'm at a loss and brain has gone to mush. If that doesn't work, then will need a new pair of eyes for this one.

Comment: @jx12345 It's loading from example.com/index.php. I can verify that $location is not actually empty, because when I echo it it contains the REQUEST_URI I expect.

Comment: @Fred That doesn't work either. Trust me when I say my brain went to mush hours ago.

Comment: use fiddler and make sure its not redirecting a few times

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem might be a redirection loop. I'm betting that `$_POST['caller']` is empty and you are redirecting multiple times to `/` which then sets REQUEST_URI to blank.

Comment: That isn't it either. I specifically make sure $_POST['caller'] is set right before that stuff in the code. I can also verify that this particular header is the one that is being used.

Comment: @OmarJackman The OP might have to add an `if` condition if `caller` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't you got some sort of weird loop happening here:

index.php loads "/lib/loginManager.php"

which redirects back to index.php with:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/?location=$location");
```

the echo just breaks the redirect

Try redirecting somewhere else, say test.php

```
header("Location: http://www.test.co.uk/test.php?location=$location");
```

and in there have something like:

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

see what happens

Comment: The key with the echo is that it happens after the header, which allows the header to still go through.

Comment: hmn true, isn't it looping though, and that's why its empty because header("Location: http://www.example.com/?location=$location"); doesn't redirect to header("Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?location=$location");

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The original index.php is www.example.com/test/directory/index.php, and loginManager.php redirects to www.example.com/?location=/test/directory/index.php. So no, it's not looping back to itself.

Comment: are you able to try it on a different server?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
global $location;
```

near the top of loginManager.php, if there's a variable scope issue that should take care of it.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't work. I really don't think it's a scope issue.